# Python, declared object with variable number of attr

Tags: python

I got a problem. I have a array of random elements, and i have object (max array = max attr in object). But if I use:

```
breadcrumbs = breadObject(element[0],element[1],element[2])
```

but if i have array with only 2 elements ([0][1]) i got error.

I try with:

```
  exec("breadcrumbs = breadObject(%s)"%string_bread)
  return breadObject
```

where string_bread is ex. str("element1","element2") but it return error:

> name 'breadObject' is not defined

Comment: Your question is very confused. What are you trying to achieve? How is `breadObject` defined? What is this dark `exec`-voodoo you are trying there? I guess you should read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), before you try anything - you seem to lack the basics.

Comment: Why are you returning `breadObject` and not `breadcrumbs`? And what happens if you try `breadcrumbs = breadObject(eval(string_bread))`? @Space_C0wb0y: it looks like he's getting the arguments of his function as a string, if my interpretation is correct. But that's sidetracking from the main point, which is that he's getting an error based on the number of arguments. user840724, could you post the object definition as Space_C0wb0y requests? Or at least post `breadObject`'s `__init__`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that understand you correctly but think you can use the following syntax:

```
breadcrumbs = breadObject(*element)
```

> Arbitrary number of arguments can be collected with *args syntax and
>   an arbitrary number of keyword arguments can be collected as a
>   dictionary with **kwargs syntax.:
>
> ```
> def function(*args, **kwargs):
>     assert isinstance(args, tuple), 'args is always a tuple'
>     assert isinstance(kwargs, dict), 'kwargs is always a dictionary'
> ```
>
> *args and **kwargs can be used to call functions with multiple arguments / keyword arguments from a tuple or dictionary